# Passing Windows User 'Token' to WCF to authenticate

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

Does anyone know how I can pass a 'token'? to a WCF service to authenticate a windows user is valid?

I want to write a wcf service that can use either U/P combo or windows login for an authentication service that will return its own standard token. The idea being that windows authentication is just 1 method my service can support.

I have see authenticating Username and password against ADFS but I won't have the password.. just the username.

Comment: Hi. I have same problem. But I didn't find any suitable solution by search. (I searched very much). Can you please tell me the final answer which you found? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify Windows Credential type for your service at both ends in the serviceModel config.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="httpService">
            <security mode="Message">
                <message clientCredentialType="Windows" algorithmSuite="Default" />
            </security>
        </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings></system.serviceModel>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733836.aspx

You will also need to configure IIS appropriately.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292114(v=vs.71).aspx